# custom angularjs directive: should I minimise the number of directives in template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am wondering if it's considered best practice to minimise the number of directives used in my own custom directive's template.

Let's take an example. Say I am building a directive to layout currencies and let the user choose one of them. It might look like this:

```
function SelectCurrencyDirective(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      currencies: '<',
      onChange: '&'
    },
    template: [
      '<div class="someContainer">',
        '<div ng-repeat="currency in currencies track by currency.symbol" ng-click="ctrl.updateSelected(currency)">{{currency.symbol}}</div>',
      '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    controller: SelectCurrencyCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  }

}

SelectCurrencyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']
function SelectCurrencyCtrl($scope){
  var ctrl = this;

  // We need to unwrap the function first
  $scope.onChange = $scope.onChange();

  ctrl.updateSelected = function(currency){
    ctrl.selected = currency; 
    $scope.onChange(currency); // activate the callback
  }
}
```

Here I am using `ng-click` from within the template. But I could choose to write a link function and listen to click event by using something like `element.on('click', doSomething)`.

My question is this: is it best practice to use the link function over the ng-click? Why? Is there a performance penalty for using the ng-click solution rather than the link function?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in AngularJS, I think it is best practice to use angular directives.
This way, AngularJS knows to do the model-changes tracking. If the model changes, then AngularJS re-renders the DOM.

So, for example

```
ctrl.updateSelected = function(currency){
    ctrl.selected = currency; 
    $scope.selectedCurrency = currency; // change on $scope
}
```

and in your HTML

```
<p>10{{selectedCurrency.symbol}}</p>
```

So the DOM will be changed and displaying the new currency symbol.